# How do i get last photo's path from photo library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

i'm using this method to take screen capture :

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage*theImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

and i want to get path for that photo so i can use it with Instagram methods

```
  NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", lastphotoTaken]];
//    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", lastphotoTaken]];

self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
self.dic = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
self.dic=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
self.dic.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Here Give what you want to share" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
[self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView: self.view animated: YES ];
```

thanx

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the asset url using:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Instead you can use:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[theImageCGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[theImageimageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){  
    if (error)
    {  
        NSLog(@"Ooops!");  
    }
    else
    {  
        NSLog(@"Saved URL : %@", assetURL);  
    }  
}];  
[library release];
```

Comment: thanks,but the url for my image is : `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=7D636703-8786-465D-B896-A0A67F0B0CCE&ext=JPG` how to convert it to this way `file://...`

Comment: @AsimNet: You can't do that with asset urls. Or store images to document directory instead of photolibrary